# can't resolve the image path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vercel

Good day guys.

I have a problem in my project related the Not found route. The problem is i have my app hosted on vercel and if you add two routes the image will disappear. For instance, if I would to do baseURL/randomthing - the image will appear, however, if I do baseURL/randomthing/anotherrandomthing the image will disappear. After debbuging I found that the problem is related to the way I import the image.

## Code causing error

`<img src="./plug-in.png" style={imageStyle} />`

If you try to add another "." syntax to the image path ../plug-in.png you will get the image back on the second route and so on.

I tried many things. Any idea why this is happening?

This is the code: [github](https://github.com/gani1000/chess-game/blob/3b48f778bc5bdc322b06095b3ae1483661a692e4/src/NotFound.jsx#L34)

And this is the app: https://chess-game-gani.vercel.app/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use dynamic paths for your images, for example:

```
<img src="/plug-in.png" style={imageStyle} />
```

This is because the path `./` will always try to take the file from the same directory that you are currently in, whereas the path `/` will always target the root directory of the site.

For example, if you are in the route domain.com/route, the `./` path would look for the image in the domain.com/route/ directory but the path `/` would look for the image in the domain.com/ directory.